# is visual studio community compatible with cuda 8.0 on windows 10 64 bit machine

Tags: visual-studio, cuda

I have a 64-bit machine with windows 10 OS and NVIDIA GeForce GT 740M display adapter. If I download Visual Studio Community, then will it be compatible with Cuda 8.0?

I checked the installation guide: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/#axzz4Uh4y5eqy. There was a table called Windows Compiler Support in CUDA 8.0. I did not understand what they meant by Native x86_64 and Cross (x86_32 on x86_64).

Please tell me what they mean, and if my machine will be compatible.

Comment: According to installation guide you mentioned, you need to install Visual Studio Community 2015. It wouldn't support `Cross (x86_32 on x86_64)`, which means you would not be able to build 32-bit (x86_32) applications on your machine. Native x86_64 compiler allows build applications for your local, x86_64 system, and by default it would always be supported on a x86_64 system.

Comment: @pSoLT: that would be a perfectly good answer if you want to add it. I'll upvote it to get this question off the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 1):

According to installation guide you mentioned, you need to install Visual Studio Community 2015. It wouldn't support `Cross (x86_32 on x86_64)`, which means you would not be able to build 32-bit (x86_32) applications on your machine. Native x86_64 compiler allows build applications for your local, x86_64 system, and by default it would always be supported on a x86_64 system.